# How to remove repositories that I don't own from GitHub dashboard

Tags: github, dashboard

I forked a repo on GitHub then I created a pull request to with my changes and then I changed my mind so I closed the pull request and I deleted the fork I made on the repo. The problem is that the repository(not the fork) is still showing in the Repositories list in the GitHub dashboard (see picture below)

[image]

See the `reeeeeeeeeee.../reeeeeeee...` repository is the one that I want to delete from there but I can't. I tried everything. 
If I go to my profile and click on repositories it isn't there because I removed the fork.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I recently had the same "issue" of having a repository on my left sidebar in my dashboard, which I thought would disappear as I removed it from my account. After contacting the Github Support Service they replied with the following message:

> The list of repositories in your sidebar will display your repositories *as well  as any repository you've interacted with* in the past 4 months. It looks like you  opened this Pull Request there:
>
> [url to PR]
>
> This would count as a contribution, which adds the repository to your contributed  to repository list. Once that activity is 4 months old, that will be removed from  your sidebar.

This is a late reply to your question and it might already be removed, however I hope this can clear up some confusion for someone else in the future.

Comment: It is gone! Thank you so much. I was so confused by this. :)

Comment: That is weird. Why don't they give me an option to remove it manually instead of clogging up my sidebar for 4 months??

Comment: Jan 2022 and here we are. What's the point of leaving it for "4 months"?

Comment: Sept 2022 and there is still no way of clearing the recent repositories list.  This "4 months" stuff is ridiculous.