# How do I remove someone else's repo on my main page?

Tags: github

Around 2/3 weeks ago I somehow got the repo `discordjs/guide` on my main page, not starred, not forked or anything, originally I tried to remove it but I couldn't figure it out so I left it alone, but now it's getting to me

[image]

When I press the link, it just directs to the official repo, there is no settings tab for me to remove it or anything, when I go to my accounts repos page, It's not there. I have gone through all the settings I could but I have not found anything related to it.

I have made an issue on it before, but that issue was closed.

Comment: I don't see it on my view of your main page: https://github.com/karizma?tab=repositories

Comment: Yea it's not on my public repositories, it's just on my main page/homepage on the left sidebar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have repositories I don't own in the repository list in the left sidebar of github.com (when I am logged in)

- some I have participated to (PR)
- some I have issues I follow
- some I have seen promoted in the "GitHub Explore the week" email I receive weekly

The [Octicons-repo.svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Octicons-repo.svg) part of [their sideNav](https://primer.style/css/components/navigation#side-nav) simply reference a "repository", but that list is generated automatically.

The best course of action is to email [GitHub support](https://support.github.com/) for asking for clarification regarding the composition of that list (that you cannot yourself directly modify)

Comment: I've done some more searching and it looks like you are right, only ways to remove are either to contact them or wait out 4 months of inactivity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154257/how-to-remove-repositories-that-i-dont-own-from-github-dashboard