# Hidden repository on github website, which I contributed but now I do not use anymore and I want to hide them

Tags: github, version-control

Hidden repository on github.com website, which I contributed (open an issue, forked).
But now I do not use them anymore and I want to hide them, these repositories are not necessary
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that some GitHub repository *is* hidden, and that this is a good thing and you have no questions about that? Or are you asking if it is possible to *hide* a GitHub repository? If the latter, who or what would you like to hide it *from?*

Comment: Now i did not use these repositories, i feel they make me mess and distracted. I want to hide them or unfollowing

Comment: @MauNguyenVan only GitHub seems to control what goes into that list, as I explain below.

Answer (score 1):

[In 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55792066/6309), the policy was that GitHub would clear out those repositories for you after 4 month of "non-interaction" (no issue or PR opened by you on that other repository)

That must have changed, because I have in my own "Recent Repositories" list very old external archived repositories, which are still listed.
So far, there is no way to control that list.

Comment: sounds like they will increase over time and make us difficult to use

Comment: Indeed, I wish there is an API allowing the user to control that list.